# ASM files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, assembly, ide, nasm

I would like to edit ASM files in Eclipse but I am not sure how to do it or what package of Eclipse I actually need. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) has an assembly editor, at least on Linux mine does and uses the GCC assembler by default.